# Spring Boot: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I created a simple Sprint Boot application.
I build a jar file with the command:

> mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage

and I run the jar file extracted by running the command:

java --jar .\target\proj-name-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

However, I get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes
> found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom
> packaging, make sure that file is correct.

This is how the plugin looks in pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <fork>true</fork>
          <mainClass><package-name>.Application</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I tried to add the file META-INF/spring.factories to src/main/resources and tried to run:

> mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage

Unfortunately, it didn't help.

I also tried to delete the entire content of .m2 repository.
Again, it didn't help.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Based on the given name `jar-with-dependencies` I suppose you are not using spring-boot-maven-plugin correctly or not all. You seemed to be using maven-assembly-plugin? Furthermore if you have configured the spring boot maven plugin correctly there is no need to call `spring-boot:repackage` separately. It should be part of the rest `mvn package`... if not there is something wrong in your pom file... it would be helpful to see your full pom file..?